# How to alias/redefine rm command in Mac terminal to do rm -v

Tags: terminal, mac, command-line

I need to see what files are removed. So I want to redefine `rm` to `rm -v`. Could you please help?

Answer (score 3):

If your shell is sh, ksh, zsh, or bash then add

```
 alias rm='rm -v'
```

to the appropriate shell start up file.

If your shell is csh or tcsh then add

```
alias rm rm -v
```

to the appropriate shell start up file.

Answer (score 0):

Your default shell will be bash, so add to `~/.profile` something like this:

`alias rm='rm -v'`

Comment: ~/.profile is for sh. - for bash use ~/.bash_profile (if you have no ~/.bash_profile then ~/.profile will work)

Comment: /bin/sh on MacOS is just /bin/bash --posix